# Chain rule in multi dimensional case?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $\xi=x-ct$ and $\tau=\omega t$ as well as
$$
u(x)=u\left(\xi+\frac{c}{\omega}\tau\right)=:u(\xi,\tau).
$$

What is then 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}u(\xi,\tau)?
$$

I think this is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}u(\xi,\tau)=(u_{\xi},u\tau)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac{c}{\omega}\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{c}{\omega}u_{\xi}
$$
by the multidimensional chain rule?

Comment: This is not 'multi-dimensional' as such, for that you would have $$u^{j}_{\tau} = (u')^j\left(\xi+\left(\frac{c}{\omega}\right)\tau \right)\left (\frac{c}{\omega}\right)$$ for $j=1 \ldots n$.

Answer (score 1):

I find your notation somehow misleading, but the final result is, by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} u(\xi,\tau)=u' \left(\xi + \frac{c}{\omega} \tau \right) \cdot \frac{c}{\omega},
$$
where $u'$ stands for the derivative of $u$.

Comment: Is u‘ the gradient here? Or what do you mean with u‘ exactly